# multiline text alignment of EditText in android

Tags: android, text, alignment, android-edittext

I want to write an android application which can perform text alignment task like microsoft word.Whole text alignment is possible but not for every line.I want to set different alignment for different line.How can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to align it to the right you can use `editText.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);` I don't think it's possible to center the text, but maybe someone knows something I don't.

Comment: editText.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT); 
This code works for whole text alignment.But I want to set right align only for line number 3  in a 5 line edittext where othere lines are left aligned.

Comment: You can't apply multiple alignments within the same editText control. You'd have to solve your problem with some kind of manual padding of the text content.